# Laravel 5.4 MailMessage::action() renders html incorrectly

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.4

I have a Notification with this code:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
  return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject("Welcome to My App")
    ->greeting('Welcome to My App')
    ->line('Hello, ' . $notifiable->name)
    ->line('You have been registered to My App.')
    ->line('Please do change your temporary password upon your login.')
    ->line('Your email: ' . $notifiable->email)
    ->line('Your temporary password: ' . $this->password)
    ->action('Login to My App', url('/'));
}
```

It seems that upon receiving the mail, it renders incorrectly and the HTML generated by the action() method is wrong.

Gmail's render:
[image]
When I inspected the HTML of the mail via Mailtrap, this is the source:

[image]

As you can see, special html characters became html entities.

I've tried updating Laravel via `composer update` but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad. I edited my `/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php` file long ago after running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`.

I tried to set alignments on that template which in turn made the email template render incorrectly.